# C/C++ Copy file with automatic recursive folder/directory creation

Tags: c++, c, winapi, file-io

In Win32 API, there is [CopyFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363851(VS.85).aspx) that literally copies a file. However, this API doesn't create folders. For example, I'd like to copy `C:\Data\output.txt` to `D:\Temp\Data\output.txt`. But, the target folders, `D:\Temp` and `D:\Temp\Data`', do not exist. In this case, this API just fails.

Is there a handy API that can automatically and recursively create directory structure on copy? Definitely, I can make such function, but I expect someone already made the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164%28VS.85%29.aspx) should do the trick. From MSDN:

> Copy and Move operations can specify
>   destination directories that do not
>   exist. In those cases, the system
>   attempts to create them and normally
>   displays a dialog box to ask the user
>   if they want to create the new
>   directory. To suppress this dialog box
>   and have the directories created
>   silently, set the `FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR`
>   flag in `fFlags`.

Comment: Thanks. `SHFileOperation` creates folder structures, but some glitch in actual file copy. It just created a folder with the name of source file name! Anyway, `SHFileOperation` + `CopyFile` did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve desired result using [SHCreateDirectoryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762131(VS.85).aspx). Here is an example:

```
inline void EnsureDirExists(const std::wstring& fullDirPath)
{
    HWND hwnd = NULL;
    const SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES *psa = NULL;
    int retval = SHCreateDirectoryEx(hwnd, fullDirPath.c_str(), psa);
    if (retval == ERROR_SUCCESS || retval == ERROR_FILE_EXISTS || retval == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
    return; //success

    throw boost::str(boost::wformat(L"Error accessing directory path: %1%; win32 error code: %2%") 
       % fullDirPath
       % boost::lexical_cast<std::wstring>(retval));

    //TODO *djg* must do error handling here, this can fail for permissions and that sort of thing
}
```

Comment: `SHCreateDirectoryEx` is deprecated, but I still didn't find anything convenient like it!