# How to recursively copy files and directories

Tags: c++, filesystems, cross-platform

With C++, is it possible to recursively copy files and directories from one path to another

- without having to use any additional libraries?
- and with platform independent functions?

Considering the following filesystem

```
src/fileInRoot
src/sub_directory/
src/sub_directory/fileInSubdir
```

I want to copy

1. all files and directories or
2. certain files and directories

from `src` to another directory `target`.

---

I've created a new question since the questions I've found are platform specific and don't include filtering:

- [C++ Copy directory recursive under unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428121/c-copy-directory-recursive-under-unix) (unix)
- [Copy directory content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325875/copy-directory-content) (linux)
- [C/C++ Copy file with automatic recursive folder/directory creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938679/c-c-copy-file-with-automatic-recursive-folder-directory-creation) (winapi)

Comment: You should use Operating System API.  The operating system is optimized for copying files, and creating directories.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Have you knowledge about performance measurements which compare OS API calls to e.g. `std::filesystem` in Linux/Windows? (my credo is to never sacrifice code readability based on assumptions or minor performance gains that are uninteresting for the use case, i.e. their impact does not affect user experience)

Comment: It’s should be noted that modern window still supports Linux posix api Carried over from window NT though usually you need to use a define and ifdef _WIN32. to add the extra underscore that Microsoft likes to add to posix function to make them slightly different under window...

Answer (score 27):

**Yes, it is possible to copy a complete directory structure** using nothing else than std C++ ... beginning with C++17 and its [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) which includes [`std::filesystem::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy).

1. Copying all files can be done using [`copy_options::recursive`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_options):

```
// Recursively copies all files and folders from src to target and overwrites existing files in target.
void CopyRecursive(const fs::path& src, const fs::path& target) noexcept
{
    try
    {
        fs::copy(src, target, fs::copy_options::overwrite_existing | fs::copy_options::recursive);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

2. To copy a certain subset of files using a filter, [`recursive_directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) can be utilized:

```
// Recursively copies those files and folders from src to target which matches
// predicate, and overwrites existing files in target.
void CopyRecursive(const fs::path& src, const fs::path& target,
                    const std::function<bool(fs::path)>& predicate /* or use template */) noexcept
{
    try
    {
        for (const auto& dirEntry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(src))
        {
            const auto& p = dirEntry.path();
            if (predicate(p))
            {
                // Create path in target, if not existing.
                const auto relativeSrc = fs::relative(p, src);
                const auto targetParentPath = target / relativeSrc.parent_path();
                fs::create_directories(targetParentPath);

                // Copy to the targetParentPath which we just created.
                fs::copy(p, targetParentPath, fs::copy_options::overwrite_existing);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

When calling the second method like

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    const auto root = fs::current_path();
    const auto src = root / "src";
    const auto target = root / "target";

    // Copy only those files which contain "Sub" in their stem.
    const auto filter = [](const fs::path& p) -> bool
    {
        return p.stem().generic_string().find("Sub") != std::string::npos;
    };
    CopyRecursive(src, target, filter);
}
```

and the given filesystem is in the working directory of the process, then the result is

```
target/sub_directory/
target/sub_directory/fileInSubdir
```

You could also pass the `copy_options` as parameter to `CopyRecursive()` for even more flexibility.

---

A list of some of the functions from `std::filesystem` which were used above:

- [`relative()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/relative) substracts the paths and heeds symlinks
  (it uses [`path::lexically_relative()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/lexically_normal) and [`weakly_canonical()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical))
- [`create_directories()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory) creates a directory for every element of the given path that does not already exist
- [`current_path()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path) returns (or changes) the absolute path of the current working directory
- [`path::stem()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/stem) returns the filename without the final extension
- [`path::generic_string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/generic_string) gives the narrow string with platform independent directory separator `/`

---

For production code, I recommend to pull the error handling out of the utility functions. For error handling, `std::filesystem` provides two methods:

1. exceptions with [`std::exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception)/[`std::filesystem::filesystem_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/filesystem_error)
2. and error codes with [`std::error_code`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code).

---

Also take into consideration, that `std::filesystem` might [not be available on all platforms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

> **The filesystem library facilities may be unavailable if a hierarchical file system is not accessible to the implementation, or if it does not provide the necessary capabilities.** Some features may not be available if they are not supported by the underlying file system (e.g. the FAT filesystem lacks symbolic links and forbids multiple hardlinks). In those cases, errors must be reported.

Answer (score 0):

Roi Danton's method is the best, but consideration that `std::filesystem` might [not be available on all platforms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem). Maybe this could be an alternative way.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

//function copy files
void cpFile(const fs::path & srcPath,
  const fs::path & dstPath) {

  std::ifstream srcFile(srcPath, std::ios::binary);
  std::ofstream dstFile(dstPath, std::ios::binary);

  if (!srcFile || !dstFile) {
    std::cout << "Failed to get the file." << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  dstFile << srcFile.rdbuf();

  srcFile.close();
  dstFile.close();
}

//function create new directory
void cpDirectory(const fs::path & srcPath,
  const fs::path & dstPath) {

  fs::create_directories(dstPath);

  for (const auto & entry: fs::directory_iterator(srcPath)) {
    const fs::path & srcFilePath = entry.path();
    const fs::path & dstFilePath = dstPath / srcFilePath.filename();
    //if directory then create new folder
    if (fs::is_directory(srcFilePath)) {
      cpDirectory(srcFilePath, dstFilePath);
    } else {
      cpFile(srcFilePath, dstFilePath);
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  const fs::path srcPath = root / "src";
  const fs::path dstPath = root / "target";

  // Copy only those files which contain "Sub" in their stem.
  cpDirectory(srcPath, dstPath);

  return 0;

}
```